# Javascript regex for matching string 'c++'

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a JavaScript code like this:

```
var regex = new RegExp(["^",skill,"$"].join(""),"i");
```

When skill = 'c++', it reports an error "SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^c++$/".

Any advice on how to write the regex in the correct way to take care of characters like "+"?

Comment: There are many, many questions covering this problem, use the site search.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2593661/251311 + https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FGuide%2FRegular_Expressions

Comment: escape the "+" sign with a backslash http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex

Comment: Amusingly, `/^c++$/` is actually a valid regex in PCRE engines, such as PHP. JavaScript lacks several useful features like this one, and lookbehinds...

Comment: Seems like you might be over-engineering to use a regex like this. Why not just `skill === 'c++'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You must escape any special regex characters from the "skill" string.

```
var escapedSkill = skill.replace(/(\W)/g, '\\$1');
var regex = new RegExp('^' + escapedSkill + '$', 'i');
regex; // => /^c\+\+$/i
```